# How to remove the numbers of the chapter and the section/subsection before their names?

Tags: titlesec, report

I used the titlesec package like this:

```latex
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\huge}{\thechapter.}{20pt}{\huge\it}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Name of Chapter}
\section{Name of Section}
\subsection{Subsection}

\end{document}
```

How I can remove tHe number before the chapter name? and how I can put the chapter's name in the center of the line? Also I want to make sections and subsections without numbers.
What I want is:

**Name of Chapter**

**Name of Section**

**Subsection**

without any numbers.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/310214/134144 could be interesting.

Answer (score 1):

To have chapters, sections, etc., without numbers put:

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}
```

in your preamble.

(To have chapters and above numbered use `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}` and to have sections and above numbered `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}` and so forth.)

Comment: I added  it and it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Add `\centering` into the format parameter of `\titleformat`.
To omit numbering just add star to the chapter command.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\huge\centering}{\thechapter.}{20pt}{\huge\it}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Name of Chapter}
\section*{Name of Section}
\subsection*{Subsection}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried to run these codes which you wrote but I got this error:  Package babel Error: You haven't loaded the option english yet.

See the babel package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.2 \select@language{english}

Comment: @amanda I am not able to replicate this problem. Please try a new blank project and only run this code, it should work fine. I guess you are missing `\usepackage[english]{babel}` somewhere in your preamble.

Comment: @ Armenthus Yes it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\huge}{}{0pt}{\filcenter\itshape}
```

However you might have problems with the  table of contents.

Comment: I do not need a table of content, so I think I can try your solution. Thanks.