# Is the \center align command not accepted in the \chapter{} command environment?

Tags: sectioning, chapters, titlesec

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\author{Joshua}
\title{Customizing Section styles}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\chapter{ \center First chapter}

\end{document}
```

The above throws an error as follows: *! Use of @chapter doesn't match its definition.*

\raggedleft works inside the chapter command, but center does not? Can anyone point out what I doing wrong here?

Comment: `\center` has never been a user command, it's the internal form of the `center` environment. This being said, have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/310205/82917.

Comment: `\center` does not exist, `\centering` does. Anyway, there is a philosophical problem here: in `\chapter` you should just give the name of the chapter --- the details about formatting it must go elsewhere. See for example: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/310205/is-there-a-way-to-center-align-chapter-titles/310214

Comment: @Rmano Well, `\center` *does* exist, but it's not supposed to be used (unless you know what you are doing). But we've found the same dupe :-)

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: @campa google-fu... ;-)